# Check for repetition in input (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

How do i check for a repeating input(letter) for a hangman game?

Example:

word is apple

input is Guess a letter: a

output is Well Done!

then guess next word

input is Guess a letter: a

output should be you already guess that letter.

my codes:

```
def checkValidGuess():
word = getHiddenWord()
lives = 10
num = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",]
#guessed = ''
while lives != 0 and word:
    print("\nYou have", lives,"guesses left")
    letter = input("Guess a letter or enter '0' to guess the word: ")
    if letter.lower() in word:
        print("Well done!", letter, "is in my word!")
        lives -= 1
    elif len(letter)>1:
        print("You can only guess one letter at a time!")
        print("Try again!")
    elif letter in num:
        print("You can only input letter a - z!")
        print("Try again!")
    #elif letter in guessed:
        #print("repeat")
    elif letter == "0":
        wword = input("What is the word?").lower()
        if wword == word:
            print("Well done! You got the word correct!")
            break
        else:
            print("Uh oh! That is not the word!")
            lives -= 1
    #elif letter == "":
        #print("Uh oh! the letter you entered is not in my word.")
        #print("Try again!")
    else:
        print("Uh oh! the letter you entered is not in my word.")
        print("Try again!")
        lives -= 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Added the codes @MateenUlhaq

Comment: Codes added @ShawnMehan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way. Start by initializing a list:

```
guesses = []
```

Then in your loop:

```
letter = input("Guess a letter or enter '0' to guess the word: ")

if letter in guesses:
    print("Already guessed!")
    continue

guesses.append(letter)
```

Comment: This error pops up :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.append`

Comment: It works but only for letters not in the word. Example, word is apple, if you input 'a' and for second input another 'a', it still detects as Well Done. but if you input 't' and for second input another 't' it says You already guessed. Its close tho :)
I think i messed up somewhere for correct letter in word?

Comment: Put this at the very top, before all your other `if`s. Be careful with how you order your `if`s.

Comment: Holyy!! THANKSS MAN, it WORKED :D Thanks soo much!!! Appreciate the help :D

Answer (score 2):

You could store the inputs in a list, let's call it `temp`.

Then you could check to see if the input exists in the list when the user goes to input a new letter.

```
guess = input()
if guess in temp:
    print "You've already guessed {}".format(guess)
else:
    #do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want to invert the order of your checks in your program so that you deal with the **try again** stuff first. Following that change, add another condition that determines if the letter matches those already guessed. This results in something like:

```
already_guessed = set()  # I made this a set to only keep unique values

while lives > 0 and word: # I changed this to test > 0
    print(f"\nYou have {lives} guesses left") # I also added an f-string for print formatting
    letter = input("Guess a letter or enter '0' to guess the word: ")
    if len(letter) > 1:
        print("You can only guess one letter at a time!")
        print("Try again!")
        continue # If you reach this point, start the loop again!
    elif letter in already_guessed:
        print("You already guessed that!")
        print("Try again")
        continue
    elif letter in num:
        print("You can only input letter a - z!")
        print("Try again!")
        continue
    elif letter.lower() in word:
        print("Well done!", letter, "is in my word!")
        lives -= 1
    else:  
        already_guessed.update(letter)
        # It wasn't a bad character, etc. and it wasn't in the word\
        # so add the good character not in the word to your already guessed 
        # and go again!
```

You would need to add your other conditional branches, but this should get you there. Good luck.

Comment: It works but only for letters not in the word.
Example, word is apple,
if you input 'a' and for second input another 'a', it still detects as Well Done.
but if you input 't' and for second input another 't' it says You already guessed.

Its close tho :)

@ShawnMehan

Comment: @Ned, I didn't finish the full `while` loop. I only addressed part of it....I was simply trying to show you how to deal with the letters already guessed. Do you need me to write the full program for you? I thought you wanted a hint, since it's clear you're doing this as a project, not the work done...

Comment: it's okay, i solved it, but now im stuck at separating them into different  functions, would you like to help me with that?