# Detect Repetition In a Letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm writing a Hangman Program, and I'm basically done, I'm just stuck on one part. So you have to detect repetition in your input, i got that part done, but then i messes up with words that have the same letter in it.
For Example:
The Word is apple:
when I input a, it says well done, the letter is in the word and prints a----
but when I input p, it says well done as well but only prints the first p, so the output looks like this ap---
but i want it to detect all p in the word, for example : app--

here are my codes for that part:

```
def getGuessedWord():
    position = word.index(letter.lower())
    global words
    words = words[:position] + letter.lower() + words[position+1:]
    print(words)
    return words
```

Comment: What is `letter` and what is `word`? As a side note, either use `global words` or `return words`, but not both, as it is totally pointless.

Comment: Preferably `return words`, as _the best use of `global` is to not use it._

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44534032/2963903

Comment: @leewz same title but different question, for that one i wanted to detect the repetition of the input and this one is to show the hidden letter that repeat in a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find all the positions of the letter in your word!

- Iterate through your word(enumerate function returns the list of index and value) and check if the value is the letter your are searching for!

Then

- modify your `words` string!

That is

```
def getGuessedWord(letter,words,word):
    for position, ltr in enumerate(word):
         if ltr == letter:
            words = words[:position] + letter.lower() + words[position+1:]
    print(words)
    return words


word='apple'
words='-'*len(word)
while '-' in words:
        words = getGuessedWord(raw_input('Enter a letter : '),words,word)
```

Output:

```
Enter a letter : l
---l-
Enter a letter : e
---le
Enter a letter : a
a--le
Enter a letter : p
apple
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is there any way to not use global but just return? do you have any social media platform we can use to discuss more about this? so i can show you the full program codes?  And Yes it does help! Thanks!

Comment: We can have the conversation here @Ned. And yeah, if you dont want to use global, then pass the words and word as parameters to your getGuessWord method! That should do!

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? so sorry, new to these stuff

Comment: mine can't work that way cause i already call the function in another  earlier part of the program so when i remove my global i get this error (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dwords' referenced before assignment)

Comment: So it totally depends on your functionality

Comment: would you mind if i send you or post my whole code and take a look at it to see how we can solve that? if no then its okay and thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem! would definitely help if I can!

Comment: i posted the whole code here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694349/not-use-global
Do have a look. Thanks! :)

Comment: you need to add the argument as I've mentioned in the answer and you have to store it in a return value! `words = getGuessedWord`

Comment: it works but now the hidden letters only show the input you key in.
For example:
the word is "apple"
when i input a its say well done : a----
then when i input p it says : -pp--
if i input l it says : ---l-

am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I solved it!!!! Thankss so much for all the help, i really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given, for example:

- `letter = 'p'`
- `word   = 'apple'`

With this list comprehension:

```
[x==letter for x in word]
```

You can detect where is a certain letter is, if it is at all, in this example it would return:

```
[False, True, True, False, False]
```

Which corresponds with the fact that only the second and third letters in a**pp**le are "p".

Because `True` **is** `1` in Python, the same happens with `0` and `False`. So, if you want a numeric value you can just sum the values in the list, by doing:

```
sum([x==letter for x in word])
```

You could try this to verify the previous statement:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

For a more detailed/specific answer, I'll need more information about how it is implemented.

Comment: do you have any facebook or other social media where we can discuss about this? i can show you the whole code and maybe you can help me detect the problem?